# Run a .war on a Docker container

Tags: docker, networking, ip, war

I'm running a Java web application on a Docker cluster running those commands:

```
PS C:\Users\Marco\test_workspace> docker run -v test_web_application.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/TestWebApplication.war -it -p 8080:8080 --network "host" -d Tomcat
```

The actual output confirms that the container is running:

[image]

At this point i want to access to the container through it's IP address from my host and i'm using the command `inspect` to identify the IP:

[image]

But, as the screenshot shows, i don't see any IP assigned.

Thus, my questions are:

**Why the command `--network "host"` to assign an IP address shared with the host didn't worked ?**

**Finally, how can i access to my web application from the host ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command option `--network="host"` isn't supported for Docker for Windows (more information: https://docs.docker.com/network/host/).
You can access your application on localhost:8080 with launch option `-p 8080:8080`.

Comment: By removing the option --network="host" the ispect command show now the cluster's IP  "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2". But i'm still not able to reach the 0.0.0.0:8080 web application.

Comment: There is something wrong with your docker's network configuration, try reaching 172.17.0.2:8080?

Comment: I'm not able to reach the localhost:8080 and the 172.17.0.1:8080. I'm trying to ping it but the machine is unreachable.

Comment: @mrk088 what is your output of `docker-machine ip default`, try accessing that <ip>:8080.

Comment: It seems to be Virtual Box failed to assign an IP address to the Docker machine using Quick Start Terminal utility. I'm looking to see the solution.